# Newbie contribution to cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

I am a newbie to cf and want to contribute cloud-foundry. Can somebody point me to a newbie guide? or anything else?

Thanks,

Comment: https://www.cloudfoundry.org/community/contribute/

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways that you can contribute.

- The easiest is to help answer questions.  You can do that here on SO, on the [CF mailing lists](https://lists.cloudfoundry.org/archives/) or on [Slack](https://slack.cloudfoundry.org/).
- Another easy way to help is with documentation.  [Docs are managed on Github](https://github.com/cloudfoundry?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=docs&type=&language=) and it's easy to submit fixes and improvements via PRs.

If you want to contribute code then you're going to need to dig in a bit more first.  Cloud Foundry is a large project made up of many different pieces, so the first step is picking a component that interests you / where you'd like to contribute.  This page in the docs has a good overview of the [different components](http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/architecture/), so it's a good reference.

Once you've narrowed it down to a specific component of CF, then check the Github page for that component and look for instructions on contributing.  Most of the teams have details about how to get started hacking on their projects.  Here's one example, which is the [Loggregator project](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/loggregator#development).

You can also check the Issues page in Github or the team's Tracker project for outstanding issues that might need resolved.  That can give you inspiration for ways to pitch in and help with the code.

Hope that helps!